# Google Chrome page bottom cut off

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, popup

Since google chrome updated to 11.0.696.60 some days ago, it cuts off the bottom of popup pages ... the status bar is displayed OUTSIDE the window at the bottom. Here is an example how it happens on the Facebook share popup, like shown in the screenshot:

[image: google chrome cuts off bottom of the page]

On the left window the share and skip button disappear totally. The page seems to be larger than the window but resizing the windows does not uncover them. When you hover over a link, the status bar appears outside the chrome window ... strange! Maximizing the window or going into fullscreen mode shows the bottom. I detect this behavior on different popup pages on different systems ...

Is this a setting thing or a bug?!?
Since I code something with this fb share function (fb jsSDK)

Comment: ok nobody seems to have an idea?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue since the last automatic update. Same bug also appears in the developer tools popout. I've noticed it's both the bottom and the RHS that is getting cut off by about 25-30px

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found now there is a thread at the chromium forum regarding this issue:

[here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=80774&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS&id=80774)

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to fixed this issue by reverting the theme back to the default.

`options > personal stuff > themes > reset to default theme`

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was occurring due to a zoom level exceeding 100%. Setting the zoom value to 100% fixed it.